# Error connecting Nodejs app to Redis on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, redis

I have a Nodejs application that I was using Redis for to handle the sessions. I am using `connect-redis` npm package. Now, I deployed the same Nodejs app to heroku but I do not know if there is a way to get a Redis server going along side my Nodejs application in Heroku.

I get the following error on `heroku logs --tail`

> 2020-04-09T03:40:31.880266+00:00 app[web.1]: throw er; // Unhandled
>   'error' event 2020-04-09T03:40:31.880267+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
>   2020-04-09T03:40:31.880267+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   2020-04-09T03:40:31.880267+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Redis connection
>   to 127.0.0.1:6379 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
>   2020-04-09T03:40:31.880268+00:00 app[web.1]: at
>   TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1137:16)
>   2020-04-09T03:40:31.880268+00:00 app[web.1]: Emitted 'error' event on
>   RedisClient instance at: 2020-04-09T03:40:31.880268+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   at RedisClient.on_error (/app/node_modules/redis/index.js:341:14)
>   2020-04-09T03:40:31.880269+00:00 app[web.1]: at Socket.
>   (/app/node_modules/redis/index.js:222:14)
>   2020-04-09T03:40:31.880269+00:00 app[web.1]: at Socket.emit
>   (events.js:311:20) 2020-04-09T03:40:31.880269+00:00 app[web.1]: at
>   emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
>   2020-04-09T03:40:31.880270+00:00 app[web.1]: at emitErrorAndCloseNT
>   (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3) 2020-04-09T03:40:31.880270+00:00
>   app[web.1]: at processTicksAndRejections
>   (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
>   2020-04-09T03:40:31.880278+00:00 app[web.1]: errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
>   2020-04-09T03:40:31.880279+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
>   2020-04-09T03:40:31.880279+00:00 app[web.1]: syscall: 'connect',
>   2020-04-09T03:40:31.880279+00:00 app[web.1]: address: '127.0.0.1',
>   2020-04-09T03:40:31.880280+00:00 app[web.1]: port: 6379
>   2020-04-09T03:40:31.880280+00:00 app[web.1]: }

I also added an addon called Heroku Redis but I get the same error message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After three days looking for an answer to this error, I will share what worked for me, get the vision.
I'm using this Heroku Redis add-on you can install via heroku-cli or directly on the dashboard on the heroku website:
Resources> click Button "Find more add-ons" and search for Heroku Redis

Via heroku-cli:

heroku addons:create heroku-redis:hobby-dev

- Create the BD Redis Get the variable data on the heroku page:

  Resources> Add-ons> Heroku Redis> Settings
- Create and configure as Redis environment variables in heroku:

REDIS_PASSWORD - provide a password generated by heroku:

REDIS_URL - provide a host created by heroku

REDIS_PORT - provide a port generated by heroku

Content of the Redis configuration file in the app:

redis.js

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  export default {
   host: process.env.REDIS_URL,
   port: process.env.REDIS_PORT,
 };
} else {
  export default {
   host: process.env.REDIS_URL,
   port: process.env.REDIS_PORT,
   password: process.env.REDIS_PASSWORD,
  };
};
```

Reference: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles

Answer (score 1):

On Heroku, your REDIS server is NO LONGER on 127.0.0.1

I'd recommend finding out the IP address of the Redis server on Heroku.

And change your Node.JS configuration for Redis server.